# Spring Security Configuration with JWT Authentication Causes HTTP 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am developing a Spring Boot application with Spring Security to handle authentication and authorization, using JWT for token generation and stateless session management. Despite my configuration, I am consistently receiving an HTTP 403 Forbidden error for all of my endpoints, including the ones that I've specifically configured to be accessible without authentication. I've tried different solutions but nothing seems to work.

Here is the main code involved in my setup:

SecurityConfig:

```
package com.khanfar.project2.Security.config;


import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthFilter JwtAuthFilter ;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .cors().and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(JwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);

        return http.build();
    }


}
```

JwtAuthFilter:

```
package com.khanfar.project2.Security.config;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private  final JwtService jwtService ;

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService ;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
         final String userEmail ;
         final String authHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION) ;
         final String Token ;
         if (authHeader==null  || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
                filterChain.doFilter(request , response);
                return;
         }
         Token = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtService.extractUsername (Token) ;

        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(Token , userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails , null , userDetails.getAuthorities() ) ;
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request  , response);
    }
}
```

JwtService:

```
package com.khanfar.project2.Security.config;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import io.jsonwebtoken.io.Decoders;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.security.Key;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Service
public class JwtService {

    private static final String SECRET_KEY = "TAREQ KHANFAR";

    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token , Claims::getSubject);
    }
    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJwt(token)
                .getBody();
    }
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(new HashMap<>() , userDetails) ;
    }
    public String generateToken (Map<String , Object> map , UserDetails userDetails ) {
         return Jwts.builder().setClaims(map)
                 .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername()  )
                 .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                 .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()+1000 * 60 * 24 ))
                 .signWith(getSignInKey() , SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                 .compact();

    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token , UserDetails userDetails ) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token) ;
        return username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token) ;
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());

    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token , Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token , Function<Claims , T > claimsTFunction) {
              final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token) ;
              return claimsTFunction.apply(claims) ;
    }
    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte[] keyBytes = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig:

```
package com.khanfar.project2.Security.config;

import com.khanfar.project2.Exception.NotFoundException;
import com.khanfar.project2.Security.user.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {


    private final UserRepository userRepository ;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> userRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(()->new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found ."));
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager (AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

AuthenticationService:

```
package com.khanfar.project2.Security.auth;

import com.khanfar.project2.Entity.Role;
import com.khanfar.project2.Security.config.JwtService;
import com.khanfar.project2.Security.user.User;
import com.khanfar.project2.Security.user.UserRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository ;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder ;

    private final JwtService jwtService ;

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager ;
    public AuthenticationResponse register(RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
        var user = User.builder()
                .name(registerRequest.getName())
                .email(registerRequest.getEmail())
                .password(passwordEncoder.encode(registerRequest.getPassword()))
                .role(Role.USER)
                .build();

        userRepository.save(user);
        var token = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return new AuthenticationResponse().builder().
                Token(token)
                .build();
    }

    public AuthenticationResponse authenticateRequest(AuthenticationRequest request) {
        authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(request.getEmail() ,request.getPassword())
        );
        var user = userRepository.findByEmail(request.getEmail()).orElseThrow();
        var token = jwtService.generateToken(user);
        return new AuthenticationResponse().builder().
                Token(token)
                .build();
    }


}
```

AuthenticationController:

```
package com.khanfar.project2.Security.auth;


import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/auth")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationController {

private final AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {

        System.out.println(registerRequest.getEmail());
         return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.register(registerRequest));

    }

    @PostMapping("/authenticate")
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationResponse> authenticateRequest(@RequestBody AuthenticationRequest Request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(authenticationService.authenticateRequest(Request));


    }


}
```

In my SecurityConfig, I've disabled CSRF and set the session management policy to SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS. I've also defined my routes starting with "/api/v1/auth/**" to be accessible without authentication.

When I make a request to my endpoints, I receive a HTTP 403 Forbidden error. My debug logs show the following:

```
2023-07-01T22:15:52.695+03:00 DEBUG 26652 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /api/v1/demo
2023-07-01T22:15:52.695+03:00 DEBUG 26652 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-07-01T22:15:52.695+03:00 DEBUG 26652 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Request requested invalid session id FFD79F7D00BB82527193D66022479C54
2023-07-01T22:15:52.697+03:00 DEBUG 26652 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2023-07-01T22:15:52.698+03:00 DEBUG 26652 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-07-01T22:15:52.701+03:00 DEBUG 26652 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-07-01T22:15:52.702+03:00 DEBUG 26652 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

This suggests to me that despite setting my application to be stateless, it is still trying to use sessions.

Could anyone help me identify what might be going wrong here and how to correctly configure stateless, JWT-based authentication in my application?

Comment: how do you send http requests to your endpoints? Are you sure you don't have any cookies within requests that might be considered as invalid session?

Comment: remember that the way you have built your application makes in insecure against XSS vulnerabilities stealing the token. JWT should not be used as sessions. AAnd anyone doing so is exposing themselfes for security risks

Answer (score -1):

I managed to resolve the issue by clearing all cookies in my browser and restarting the application. It appears that an old session cookie was interfering with the request. For anyone facing a similar issue, remember to clear your browser cookies when switching from stateful to stateless session management in your application. When testing your APIs, consider using tools like Postman or curl for better control over the request headers.